# How to use loadSource() with strings instead of m3u8 playlists?

Tags: hls.js

In the demo by galeksandrp:
https://github.com/galeksandrp/hls.js/tree/hlstorrent he uses webtorrent and hls.js to create a P2P stream.
The demo works perfectly for me but I will need to use the strings variable instead of loading an external playlist with hls.loadSource('193039199_mp4_h264_aac_ld_7.m3u8').

Has anyone ever done something similar? Simply trying to load the string gives: 
"Error trying to parse base URL" which is understandable since URLToolkit tries to build an absolute URL out of anything within the brackets of loadSource and thus it won't have a URL it can parse.

The strings variable has the same content as '193039199_mp4_h264_aac_ld_7.m3u8'

```
strings = ['#EXTM3U',
         '#EXT-X-VERSION:3',
         '#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD',
         '#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10',
         '#EXTINF:10.000,',
         'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:5493683624141c381fa19c9ed3bf00be2e0d96af',
         '#EXTINF:10.000,',
         'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:1ec3227aabe562cf2b244a41b93fa0a1aa423f4d',
         '#EXTINF:10.000,',
         'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:3cbd1622487f202f11aea838b0984a1478054456',
         '#EXTINF:10.000,',
         'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:9cf20cfe4fd1745ea4f72067192681b30b52a8c5',
         '#EXTINF:10.000,',
         'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:0c96911da7c860a9ae2a26ed8a96c10590508407',
         '#EXT-X-ENDLIST'];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var enc = new TextEncoder("utf-8");
hls.loadSource(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([enc.encode(strings.join('\n'))])));
```

Explaination: You only need to turn playlist text to URL, no need to write [custom playlist loader](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/doc/API.md#ploader).

- Join array of strings to text (if needed), and turn text to [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) with [`enc.encode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder/encode).
- Then turn result to [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) with `new Blob([])`.
- Then turn result to `blob:` virtual URL with [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL).

Example:

- https://rawgit.com/galeksandrp/hls.js/hlstorrent-blob-url/client.js
- https://rawgit.com/galeksandrp/hls.js/hlstorrent-blob-url/server.js

---

```
var hls = new Hls({fLoader: customLoader, pLoader: customLoaderP});
```

Explaination: You can also write [custom playlist loader](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/doc/API.md#ploader) because default is hardcoded to use XHR and therefore:

- does not support playlist as text
- does not support playlist as ArrayBuffer and derivatives (Blob, FileReader).
- only support usual and `blob:` urls

Example of that custom playlist loader is [`customLoaderP`](https://github.com/galeksandrp/hls.js/blob/46f12e4a3957d5a200bd2f66f76e1e64e2928a7a/client.js#L6) function in which you discovered playlist in form of array of strings.

Please also note that my example is optimized for Live P2P, and therefore new torrent created for **each** 10seconds chunk, which may be not needed if you distributing VOD/DVR. With usual videos you can pass all chunks in single torrent.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed.
The next step is making it work with live streaming video.